# jquery : Setting value in hidden input upon onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML file with a simple drop down list.

Upon selecting one of the choices, I want the choice to be stored in a hidden input.

```
 <div id ="mainContent">
    <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Category : </span> <select id="selectid" name="filecategory">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
           </select>
          <br /><br />
 <input type="hidden"  name="filecategory" value="XXX" /> 
    </div>
```

I did some research online and came up with this handler code upon detecting a change event in the drop down list.

```
 $("#selectid").change(function(){
                   alert('change called');
                });
```

Can someone tell me how I can set the hidden input via this handler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved here:

```js
$("#selectid").change(function(){
  $("input[name='filecategory']").val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectid" name="filecategory">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
           
<input type="hidden"  name="filecategory" value="XXX" />
```